# How to load AngularJS content via jQueryUI AJAX?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery

Our teams have inherited a jQuery Mobile project from another office and now we are trying to implement new features using AngularJS. The idea is also to migrate the whole jQuery website to AngularJS, step by step. Ideally, we would star the project from scratch in AngularJS, but that's not feasible for the time being.

The thing is, we have a jQuery tabs control which loads its tabs content via AJAX. All the current tabs are jQuery and we need to implement a new one, wrapping AngularJS code around it. But this is not working...

I've created a simple example to demonstrate the problem.

The live example can be found here:

http://ricardoamaral.net/jquery/

Click the "Ajax Loaded" tab and see for yourself that the Angular variable is not updated with the value defined in the Angular controller.

The following is code from the example above:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ngSampleApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Tabs</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax.html">Ajax Loaded</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1" ng-controller="sampleController">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

    var app = angular.module('ngSampleApp', []);

    app.controller("sampleController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.demoText = "Hello World!"
    }]);
</script>
```

**ajax.html**

```
<p><strong>This content was loaded via ajax.</strong></p>
<p>{{demoText}}</p>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you create a directive for the jquery part.

Comment: this isn't related to [jQuery-Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Comment: @lucuma That would require a lot of refactoring. Which we will be doing in the form of getting rid of jQuery to Angular. We are looking for an "easier" solution to workaround the problem in the mean time.

Comment: @Omar Sorry, removed the tag.

Comment: creating a directive for your issue is the easier way of addressing it.

Comment: putting angular  on top of jQuery is bad approach....needs to work the other way, angular first, use directives for jQuery plugins. There are already directives for jQUery UI available. Not hard to tap into jQUery UI events within a directive to call angular `$apply` even if you make own directives

Comment: Could someone provide an example of that in an answer below? If possible, talking my example and "fix it" with this directive approach?

Comment: You might check out https://github.com/wlepinski/angularjs-jqueryui or do some googling on jquery UI angular directives.  Plenty of info and that is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have importing templates with angular expressions is angular is not aware of the new content in DOM. Whenever you insert html from outside angular, you need to use `$compile` so that angular can process all expressions and directives ( including the `ng-directives`)`

Here's a very simple example of integrating jQueryyUI tabs into a directive to make your demo do what you expect

HTML

```
<div id="tabs" jq-tabs>
```

JS

```
app.directive('jqTabs', function($compile, $timeout) {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.tabs({/* initalize UI tabs*/
      /* using jQueryUI tabs API, compile angular content in load event callback*/
      load: function(event, ui) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $compile($(ui.panel).contents())(scope)
        });
      }

    });
  }
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jQBkNrazuJopNvfcgA1m?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Is the `$timeout` really necessary since the timeout value is 0?

Comment: delays digest... need a chance for new content to render. Did you try it without it?

Comment: It doesn't work without it... What if the timeout returns and the content has not been loaded yet?

Comment: why would that happen? I think you need to read up on angular digest cycles