# Angular controller is not called during ajax call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, symfony

I have an action in Symfony which renders the following html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div ng-init="loadTarget('http://url/target')" ng-bind-html="target_content"></div>
</div>
```

http://url/target is also an action in Symfony which renders
The following html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <div ng-bind-html="con"></div>
</div>
```

The angular code is below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $scope.loadTarget = function(ajaxUrl) {

    $http({
      method: 'HTML',
      url: ajaxUrl
    }).success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.target_content = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
    });
  };
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    var v = '<b>Hello World</b>';
    $scope.con = $sce.trustAsHtml(v);
}]);
```

Both view extend a layout that imports the dependencies as well as contains the ng-app='app' call.

The problem is that the second controller(Ctrl2) is never called. At the same time if I put the url of the second action directly in the browser and hit 'Go', it does execute and loads data as expected. This is obviously a very simplified example, which, by the way, I could not get to work in plunker as it won't make an ajax call at all saying that it is "Unable connect to any application instances", but here is the link just in case.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YRv3M1ZX7FMiFICAUq7m

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK only loading the html won't execute angular. You have to recompile the scope for this. Like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544144/how-to-load-angularjs-content-via-jqueryui-ajax

Comment: Thanks for your help!